# Change div color on parents background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a cube change based on its background color. I hoped this was possible by giving an element a bit of a transparent background and a filter to invert the color of its parent background. But of course, it just inverts its own color.

In this example, it works with javascript by telling it to change `background-color` at (for example) `document.height()`. But I also want it to invert the color when it goes over an image.

Is there maybe some way to do this? With `:hover` you can do stuff like `.section1:hover cube{ ... }` so is there maybe a pseudo-element like `:overlaying`?

```css
.cube{
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: calc( 50vw - 25px );
  bottom: 50px;
  background-color: RGBA(255,255,255, .2);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.section{
  height: 600px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.section1{
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
}

.section2{
  background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

.section3{
  background-color: #AAFFAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="section section1"></div>
<div class="section section2"></div>
<div class="section section3"></div>

<div class="cube"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode):

```css
.cube {
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: calc( 50vw - 25px);
  bottom: 50px;
  background-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.section {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

.section3 {
  background-color: #AAFFAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="section section1"></div>
<div class="section section2"></div>
<div class="section section3"></div>

<div class="cube"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Awesome! The only downside is that it's not for IE but I don't think there are a lot of other options.

Comment: @Jeremy who's IE ? ... never heard about :)

Comment: IE is that (most of the time) red annoying block that you find at https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode ;)