# Make relative div clip static logo on scroll - CSS

Tags: css, scroll, clip

I want to achieve the following effect on a single-page scrolling website.

The site is divided in different section (usign the `<section>` tag of course) and there is a fixed position logo in the bottom left.

I want to be able to mask/clip the logo color depending on which section is below it. For starters I put the same logo twice on top of each other so there are basically two z-indexed logos one on top of another.

Below are some quick mock-ups for reference.

Section 1:
[image]

Section 2:
[image]

Effect I want while scrolling:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494026/change-div-color-on-parents-background-color/49494243#49494243

Comment: hmm, mix-blend mode is interesting but is not exactly what I'm looking for since it's some sort of layer effect. I want to specifically choose what exactly im showing/hiding. Thanks anyway, I might need this someday

Comment: another idea if you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998036/how-to-create-image-scrolling-blend-effect-with-css/48998170#48998170 ;)

Comment: yeah this could potentially work. Feel free to add it an an answer so i can mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: No need to add the same answer, if you think it's suitable for your you can simply upvote the other one ;) ... And maybe you will still have issue after trying and you can update your question if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kindly pointed out above the answer to this question can be found here:

[How to create image scrolling blend effect with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998036/how-to-create-image-scrolling-blend-effect-with-css/48998170#48998170)

I was hoping to try and tweak this a bit and try an approach either with the `clip` property or using both `height` and `overflow:hidden`. I can't find the time to try it right now but I will update accordingly if I ever do.